# Azure DevOps Build Verification is stuck on "unable to queue build"

Tags: azure-devops

I want to trigger a [Pipeline Build Validation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCxgX.png) every time I create a new PR in an Azure Repo.
For some reason, the pipeline that has the `TEST` word in it isn't triggered when creating a PR.
The error from the PR is: `unable to queue build`. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTsMD.png). As you can the, the PR doesn't recognize the `TEST` pipeline.

For 2 specific pipelines, the validation does work: `Sanity Check` & `YAML Sanity test`. Both of them are YAML based pipelines. `TEST` is a Classic Pipeline.

I tried to change the location of the `TEST` Pipeline to another location in Azure DevOps (root directory, etc) but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

After some long debugging, it turns out the Pipelines can only be triggered from the source repo.
[Source repo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TeH7K.png)